# Typing dependent pattern matching

Tags: type-theory, semantics, dependent-types, inductive-datatypes

I'm curious on how to type a **dependent** pattern matching in a functional language. What should the rule for typing

```
match e with
| C_1 a_1_1 a_1_2 ... a_1_n1 -> e_1
| C_2 a_2_1 a_2_2 ... a_2_n1 -> e_2
| ...
| C_m a_m_1 a_m_2 ... a_m_nm -> e_m
end
```

be, where e is of type T, which has constructors C_i for each i.

I think that to prove that the pattern match has a type T', we need to prove
that each e_i has type T' under specific assumptions, but I can't quite pinpoint those assumption to add into the context.

Comment: You'll need to know the types of each `C_i` and in particular what it's arguments are, but that's not the hard part. The hard part is that a type may be indexed over certain type arguments so that when you pattern match you restrict what they could be.

Comment: OK, do you happen to know of a book/article that covers this in detail?

Comment: Peter Dybjer has a number of papers on the subject, I think you might find his work on indexed inductive types helpful and relevant. http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~peterd/papers/Indexed_IR.pdf I think covers everything you would find with dependent pattern matching in Agda for example.

Answer (score 6):

In general matching with dependent types can be quite subtle! You'll note that in the [Coq documentation](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/Reference-Manual003.html#term-syntax) that the *extended* pattern-matching syntax is

```
match t as x in T1 return T2 with
    | C1 a1 ... an
    ...
```

In particular, ommiting any of the `as`, `in` or `return` clauses can prevent type inference of the statement.

Intuitively, if the type of (say) constructor $C_1$ is
$$ \Pi(x_1:A_1)\ldots(x_k:A_k).I\ \vec{p}$$
and the type of the matched term $t$ is
$$ I\ \vec{v}$$
then you get the *constraint*
$$ \vec{p}[\vec{a}/\vec{x}]\simeq \vec{v}$$
which may lead to an undecidable problem, as explained in [Goguen *et al*.](http://cs.ru.nl/~james/RESEARCH/goguen2006.pdf)

Then all you need is for each right hand side to correspond to the appropriate instance of the return type. This return type may depend on $t$, so the `return` clause specifies the pattern of the return type as a function of $x$ (which represents $t$ through the `as` clause).

More formally, each $e_i$ must have type:

$$ T_2[C_i\ \vec{a}/x]$$

and the type of the whole match expression is
$$ T_2[t/x]$$

More details can be found [here](http://flint.cs.yale.edu/cs428/coq/doc/Reference-Manual018.html).